# How to Add List Of Project Task Details To The 'net.sf.mpxj.Task task' In C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-project, mpxj

i have a c# object having ProjectInfo With ProjectTasks, now how can i add these projectTasks to the 'net.sf.mpxj.Task task' In C#

while i am creating new object for net.sf.mpxj.Task, then it is showing error that 'the type net.sf.mpxj.Task has no constructors defined', so it cannot create new object, then how can i add projectTasks.

Below is the sample Code that it does not work:

```
     List<net.sf.mpxj.Task> tasks=new List<net.sf.mpxj.Task>();

            foreach (var pTask in projectInfo.ProjectTasks)
            {

                net.sf.mpxj.Task task = new net.sf.mpxj.Task();

                        task.TaskId=ptask.TaskId;
                        task.Name = pTask.TaskName;
                        task.Notes = pTask.Description;
                         task.Start=pTask.EstimatedStartDate.ToJavaDate();
                         task.Finish  = pTask.EstimatedEndDate.ToJavaDate();
                        task.Estimated = true;
                        task.Priority = null;
                        task.Type = null;

                    tasks.Add(task);

            }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you are not creating MPXJ object rightly. Please follow following code to create MPXJ tasks. Here I am creating MSPDI file which xml format of MS Project.

```
    ProjectFile project = new ProjectFile();

    foreach (var pTask in projectInfo.ProjectTasks)
    {
        Task task = project.AddTask();
        task.Name = pTask.TaskName;
        task.Notes = pTask.Description;
        task.Start=pTask.EstimatedStartDate.ToJavaDate();
        task.Finish  = pTask.EstimatedEndDate.ToJavaDate();
        task.Estimated = true;
        task.Priority = null;
        task.Type = null;
    }

    TaskContainer taskCon = project.AllTasks;
    if (taskCon.Size() >= 1)
    {
        java.io.OutputStream outs = null;
        try
        {
            // string serverPath = Server.MapPath(fileName);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullFileName))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(fullFileName);
            }
            MSPDIWriter writer = new MSPDIWriter();
            outs = new java.io.FileOutputStream(fullFileName);
            writer.Write(project, outs);
            outs.close();

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullFileName))
            {
                string fileName = "ProjectTask.xml";
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                response.Clear();
                response.ClearContent();
                response.ClearHeaders();
                response.Buffer = true;
                response.ContentType = "Application/msproject";
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
                byte[] data = client.DownloadData(fullFileName);
                response.BinaryWrite(data);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (outs != null)
            outs.close();
        }
    }
```

I did good research in it. Please let me know if need any more help on this.